# How do you remove a FPS setting in xrandr --output?

Tags: 20.04, xrandr

When I xrandr in terminal, this shows up:

```
   1920x1080    120.00*+  60.00  
   1680x1050    120.00  
   1280x1024    120.00  
   1440x900     120.00  
   1280x800     120.00  
   1280x720     120.00  
   1024x768     120.00  
   800x600      120.00  
   640x480      120.00
```

I want to remove the 60 fps part of the 1920x1080 setting, how can you do this? Using Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The `60.00` value is an optional refresh rate that is supported by the display device, so there really is no need to "remove" it. That said, if you *really* wanted to, you could try with something like this:

```
xrandr --delmode <output> <name>
```

Based on your output, this would result in a command that looks something like this:

```
xrandr --delmode eDP-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Be sure to replace `eDP-1` with the proper output for your machine.